# How to add fonts to docker image

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm using node node:15-slim for building nodejs image. Apparently this image doesn't have any fonts included. So `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)` appears.
I added `.fonts/Ubuntu-Light.ttf` into my project and tried to copy that file in Dockerfile

```
FROM node:15-slim
COPY .fonts .fonts/ <-- Here I copy 
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY src/* /app/src/
COPY tsconfig.json /app/
RUN npm run build
```

But it doesn't help. I don't want to use not slim version and hoping to find solution
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure that the config file is actually there, and if so, set an environment variable to where the config file is.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/492033/fontconfig-error-cannot-load-default-config-file

Answer (score 1):

node-slim does not have fontconfig. You must install it yourself. Add this in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q libfontconfig1
```